# Hierarchical optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am looking to find a point of a function $f(x,y)$ that minimizes $f$ with respect to $x$ and at the same time fulfills $x=y$ (but the point is not necessarily a minimum with respect to $y$). I would consider this a hierarchical optimization. Here a simple example:

```
FindRoot[y == x /. NMinimize[(x - y^2)^2, x][[2]], {y, 1}]
```

This code does not work. What I intend to do is find $y$ such that $y==x$ and $x$ minimizes $f(x,y)=(x-y^2)^2$. The solution would be $y=1$. Is there a syntactically correct way to do this in Mathematica?

**Edit:** The example was poorly chosen because $f$ has a minimum with respect to $y$ as well at $x=y=1$. Here is a modified example:

```
f[x_, y_] := (x - y^2)^2 + Exp[y]
```

This is the result I would like to obtain:

```
Block[{y = 1}, NMinimize[f[x, y], x][[2]]]
(* {x -> 1.} *)
```

However, minimizing $f[x,x]$ leads to a wrong solution:

```
NMinimize[{f[x, x], x > 0.5}, x]
(* {x -> 0.5} *)
```

With pen-and-paper math, the solution I am aiming for reads

1. Minimize with $f$ respect to $x$ yields $x=y^2$.
2. Solve $x=y$ gives $y=y^2$ or $y=0,1$.

I am looking for a numerical method to obtain the same result.

Comment: Only use `NMinimize` and replace `y` with `x`

Comment: For my first example this approach worked. I have modified the example to better illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := (x - y^2)^2 + Exp[y]
g[y_?NumericQ] := x /. NMinimize[f[x, y], x][[2]]
FindRoot[g[y] == y , {y, 1.25}]
```

> {y->1.}

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Why does it not work when writing it in one line, i.e., without the auxiliary function `g`?

Comment: the `g` function ensures that `NMinimize` is only evaluated with a numeric `y` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the minimum by taking the derivative and setting equal to zero.

```
f[x_, y_] := (x - y^2)^2 + Exp[y];
sol = Solve[D[f[x, y], x] == 0, x]
```

This gives {{x -> y^2}}, and you now want to solve for when both sides of this are equal:

```
Solve[y == First@(x /. sol), y]

{{y -> 0}, {y -> 1}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this analytical approach does not work for my actual problem, because `Solve` is limited to very simple (polynominal) functions. I need a numerical method.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with **Bill S**'s answer, you can combine the steps using `Solve`

```
Solve[{D[f[x, y], x] == 0, x == y}, {x, y}]
(* {{x -> 0, y -> 0}, {x -> 1, y -> 1}} *)
```

or use `Reduce` which tends to be a bit more robust

```
Reduce[2 (x - y^2) == 0 && x == y, {x, y}]
(* (x == 0 || x == 1) && y == x *)
```

and if you need a numerical solution

```
NSolve[{D[f[x, y], x] == 0, x == y}, {x, y}, Reals]
(* {{x -> 1., y -> 1.}, {x -> 0., y -> 0.}} *)
```

Comment: +1 for a numerical solution that is also much faster than george's version. George's solution, however, works with more complicated functions, where `NMinimize` is required to find the minimum (solving for derivative == 0 often fails when the functions involved are non-trivial).